# ReentrantReadWriteLock: what's the difference between ReadLock and WriteLock?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock, reentrantreadwritelock

What I know is:

- [`ReadLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.html) and [`WriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.html) affect each other somehow
- `WriteLock` is just like *synchronized*
- `ReadLock` seems cannot work alone

Answer (score 161, accepted):

## readLock.lock();

- This means that if any other thread is **writing** (i.e. holds a
  write lock) then stop here until no other thread is writing.
- Once the lock is granted no other thread will be allowed to **write**
  (i.e. take a write lock) until the lock is released.

---

## writeLock.lock();

- This means that if any other thread is **reading *or* writing**, stop
  here and wait until no other thread is reading or writing.
- Once the lock is granted, no other thread will be allowed to **read
  *or* write** (i.e. take a read or write lock) until the lock is released.

---

Combining these you can arrange for only one thread at a time to have write access, but as many readers as you like can read at the same time except when a thread is writing.

Put another way. Every time you want to **read** from the structure, take a **read** lock. Every time you want to **write**, take a **write** lock. This way whenever a write happens no-one is reading (you can imagine you have exclusive access), but there can be many readers reading at the same time so long as no-one is writing.

Comment: +1 good explanation. Just for clarification, by `one` you mean `thread`.

Answer (score 23):

The documentation for [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) makes this clear:

> A ReadWriteLock maintains a pair of associated locks, one for read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.

So you can have many readers at a time, but only one writer - and the writer will prevent readers from reading, too. This is useful if you've got some resource which is safe to read from multiple threads, and where reading is much more common than writing, but when the resource is not *actually* read-only. (If there are no writers and reading is safe, there's no need for a lock at all.)

Comment: what if there are 100 readers and in between 1 writer wants to acquire a lock, so in this case readers will be interrupted ? or writer has to wait till current readers release the lock.

Comment: @Vipin: The writer has to wait.

Comment: Now Your answer is perfect :)

Comment: For example, reader A is reading. Then writer B is come so writer B will wait. While B is waiting, reader C comes. So reader C will wait until B run and finish, or reader C can read ASAP. thanks.

Comment: @hqt reader C will start to read and B will wait for it to finish. C will only wait if B already started writing.

Comment: If you will not write ReadLock -> it will upgrade Readers and result will Deadlock (Allowing a read thread to upgrade would lead to a deadlock as more than one thread can try to upgrade its lock)

Answer (score 10):

When a thread acquires a `WriteLock`, no other thread can acquire the `ReadLock` nor the `WriteLock` of the same instance of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, unless that thread releases the lock. However, multiple threads can acquire the `ReadLock` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Using ReadWriteLock, you can improve performance of an application in which more reads are performed on a shared object than writes.

ReadWriteLock maintains two locks for read and write operations. Only one lock either read or write can be acquired at the same time. But multiple threads can simultaneously acquire read lock provided write lock is not acquired by any thread.

ReentrantReadWriteLock is an implementation of ReadWriteLock. It gives write lock to the longest waiting thread if multiple thread are not waiting for read lock. If multiple threads are waiting for read lock, read lock is granted to them.

A reader which acquired read lock can reacquire read lock, similarly, writer can reacquire write lock and can acquire read lock also.

See http://www.zoftino.com/java-concurrency-lock-and-condition-examples

Comment: just a heads up, that zoftino link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Consider a situation: In a case when data structures are `read-mostly` - they are mutable and are sometimes modified, but most accesses involve mostly reading, so in these case we can relax the locking mechanism in away that we can allow multiple readers to access the data structures instead of readers waiting while one reader has released the lock. As long as each thread is guaranteed an up to date view of the shared data and no thread modifies it while the readers are viewing it, there will no problems. This is what read write allows : a resource can be accessed by multiple readers or a single writer at a time, but not both.